# Efficient way to concatenate dataframe with its columns reversed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One fairly recurring pattern I have is creating a dataframe that combines another dataframe with its columns reversed. Here's a small example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(5), "b": range(6, 1, -1)})
combined = pd.concat([df, df.rename(columns={"a": "b", "b": "a"})], ignore_index=True)
```

Is there a more efficient approach to achieving this operation (esp. with many, many rows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert values to numpy array and use `np.concatenate` with reverse order of array by indexing `a[:, ::-1]`, last pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = df.to_numpy()
combined = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([a, a[:, ::-1]]), columns=df.columns)
print(combined)
   a  b
0  0  6
1  1  5
2  2  4
3  3  3
4  4  2
5  6  0
6  5  1
7  4  2
8  3  3
9  2  4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the underlying numpy array and [`vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) on the array and its reversed version, then generate a new DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np

a = df.to_numpy()
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([a, a[:, ::-1]]), columns=df.columns)
```